# Reading from text file in MPI

Tags: c

I am trying to read int and double from txt file.
When I run the process in the console, everything works, but when I work through the MPI with a single process it gives me an error:

```
$ ./a.out
job aborted:
rank: node: exit code [: error message]
0: DESKTOP-QUJB667: -1073740791: process 0 exited without calling finalize
```

I used only two commands to read from the file:

```
FILE * file = fopen ("pixel.txt", "r");
fscanf (file, "% d", & numOfPixelsInFile);
```

The problem of reading from a file is only the initial stage of a broader task that I have to do.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct Pixel 
{
    int id;
    int x;
    int y;
    float rgb[3];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int  namelen, numprocs, myid;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

    if (myid == 0) 
    {       
        FILE* file = fopen("pixel.txt", "r");

        //Pixel arguments
        int id, x, y;
        float rgb1;
        float rgb2;
        float rgb3;

        int numOfPixelsInFile = 0;
        fscanf(file, "%d", &numOfPixelsInFile);
        printf("Num of pixels: %d\n", numOfPixelsInFile);

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPixelsInFile; i++)
        {
            fscanf(file, "%d %d %d %e %e %e", &id,
                &x, &y, &rgb1, &rgb2, &rgb3);
            printf("%d %d %d %e %e %e\n", id, x, y, rgb1, rgb2, rgb3);
        }

        fclose(file);       
    }
    else 
    {
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What arguments (if any) are you sending to the program?

Comment: The program does not accept any arguments.

Comment: Your code works fine on my side, even if it's launched on multiple ranks. Could you try a simple Hello world MPI program to test your MPI installation? http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-hello-world/.

Comment: I realized what the problem was, I just had to place the .txt file in the folder where the wmpiexec file was located.
Thank you all for your help!